# NFC Flutter iOS not Working (only showing Ready to Scan Animation

Tags: flutter, dart, package, nfc

I trying to scan nfc tag using the package `nfc_manager (nfc_manager: ^3.2.0)`. In Android, it all goes fine but in iOS, I only get the animation ready to scan but no devices are found.
I tried lots of values in the ***info.plist***, I tried this all file also:
https://github.com/okadan/nfc-manager/blob/master/ios/Runner/Info.plist
(comes from a example app from the package).

I also tried with `pollingOptions: {NfcPollingOption.iso14443, NfcPollingOption.iso15693}`
I have the nfc capability turned ON.

Here goes my fvm flutter doctor:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.7.11, on macOS 13.3.1 22E772610a darwin-arm64, locale en-US)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.2)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.3)
[✗] Chrome - develop for the web (Cannot find Chrome executable at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome)
    ! Cannot find Chrome. Try setting CHROME_EXECUTABLE to a Chrome executable.
[✓] Android Studio (version 2022.1)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.77.1)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)
[✓] HTTP Host Availability

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

Here goes part of my widget:

```
class NfcEnableWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final BuildContext contextParent;
  const NfcEnableWidget({Key? key, required this.contextParent})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  _NfcEnableWidgetState createState() => _NfcEnableWidgetState();
}

class _NfcEnableWidgetState extends State<NfcEnableWidget> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    NfcManager.instance.startSession(
      
  // Here.  NOTE: all options are specified by default.
  //pollingOptions: {NfcPollingOption.iso14443, NfcPollingOption.iso15693},
      onDiscovered: (tag) async {
        // Do something with the valid tag data
        final result = await widget.contextParent
            .read<TagOnBoardingCubit>()
            .checkNfcCode(tag);
        if (result != null) {
          ScaffoldMessenger.of(widget.contextParent).showSnackBar(
            SnackBar(
              content: Text(result),
            ),
          );
        }
      },
    );
  }
```

I'm trying to resolve this issue during the past few weeks.

Answer (score 0):

What's your iOS version? Not all the iPhones support NFC.

The phone must be iPhones with iOS 13 or later and later than iPhone 6.

Read: https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/nfc

Once, you call startSession, the NFC popup shows up. And it waits until the user tags a NFC.

If it's not a Device or OS problem, then, you might set it up incorrectly.

Add this `Info.plist`.

```
<key>com.apple.developer.nfc.readersession.felica.systemcodes</key>
    <array>
        <string>8005</string>
        <string>8008</string>
        <string>0003</string>
        <string>fe00</string>
        <string>90b7</string>
        <string>927a</string>
        <string>86a7</string>
        <string>04D1</string>
        <string>80DE</string>
        <string>865E</string>
        <string>8592</string>
        <string>8B5D</string>
        <string>8FC1</string>
        <string>FE00</string>
    </array>
    <key>com.apple.developer.nfc.readersession.iso7816.select-identifiers</key>
    <array>
        <string>A0000002471001</string>
        <string>A000000003101001</string>
        <string>A000000003101002</string>
        <string>A0000000041010</string>
        <string>A0000000042010</string>
        <string>A0000000044010</string>
        <string>44464D46412E44466172653234313031</string>
        <string>D2760000850100</string>
        <string>D2760000850101</string>
        <string>00000000000000</string>
    </array>
```

And also, check other settings in https://medium.com/@codetrade/implement-nfc-in-flutter-to-transfer-peer-to-peer-data-64efeaa5377c

[flutter_nfc_kit](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_nfc_kit) can be analternative solution.